# java: Error:Could not find or load main class dailyreport.Add_employee

Tags: java

I am working on java.I am getting an error while running a form named '`Add_employee`' as '`Could not find or load main class dailyreport.Add_employee`'.I dont know why this error is coming.

Plz can anyone help me to solve the error?

Comment: can you post your source code?

Comment: I am not able to post source code because its to lengthy.

Comment: @Harshali `dailyreport` is the package name and `Add_employe`e is the name of the java class? If so `Add_employee` must exist inside package `dailyreport` and your physical java class file must be `Add_employee`

Comment: I'd consider using normal Java naming conventions; it won't solve your problem, but IMO it's a good habit to get in to.

Answer (score 0):

Your class `Add_employee` should be in package `dailyreport` and contains `public static void main(String args[])` method

```
package dailyreport;

public class Add_employee 
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
      //...
   }
}
```